# mysql select only unique row

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to select only unique row from the table, can someone help me out?

```
 SELECT * FROM table
 where to_user = ? 
 and deleted != ? 
 and del2 != ?
 and is_read = '0' 
  order by id desc


+----+-----+------+
| id | message_id |
+----+-----+------+
|  1 | 23         | 
|  2 | 23         | 
|  3 | 23         | 
|  4 | 24         | 
|  5 | 25         | 
+----+-----+------+
```

I need something like

```
+----+-----+------+
| id | message_id |
+----+-----+------+
|  3 | 23         | 
|  4 | 24         | 
|  5 | 25         | 
+----+-----+------+
```

Comment: So you only need the largest `id ` for a particular `message_id`?

Comment: @SWeko if the `message_id` is similar I just want only the last one.

Comment: If by *similar* you mean *same*, and the last one is the largest one, then mine or Aziz's answers will do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT MAX(id), message_id
FROM tablename
GROUP BY message_id
```

and if you have other fields then:

```
SELECT MAX(id), message_id
FROM tablename
WHERE to_user = ? 
AND deleted != ? 
AND del2 != ?
AND is_read = '0'
GROUP BY message_id 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the largest id for a particular message_id

```
SELECT max(id), message_id FROM table
 where to_user = ? 
 and deleted != ? 
 and del2 != ?
 and is_read = '0'
group by message_id 
  order by id desc
```

Answer (score -1):

Try DISTINCT keyword. This will work definitely:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(message_id), id FROM table;
```